# How to use mongodb-document-upload plugin from jenkins in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to connect mongodb server for a jenkins pipeline job to save all the job artifacts in mongodb.

So recently I came across this mongodb-document-upload plugin which is available in post build section for a freestyle job that helps in uploading all json artifacts to mongodb. So I want to know how to use this plugin in a pipeline job? ( Plugin works fine in a freestyle job).

Comment: Shruthi, you can expect better responses when you ask a question something like "I tried to do <abc> using <pqr> command but it threw <xyz> error." The above question is very open

Comment: I am looking out for a  syntax to use mongodb-document-upload plugin in a jenkins pipeline job in post build section.